# How to create a function that finds the number of equal values in two vectors In R

Tags: r

I have vector  *a = 10:15* and vector *b = 13:17*, So How can I create a function that tells me the number of equal values. The result is *3*. (because the same values are 13,14,15). Thank you

Comment: try: `length(intersect(a, b))`

Answer (score 1):

```
foo <- function(x, y) length(intersect(x, y)) 

a <- 10:15
b <- 13:17
foo(a, b)
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `duplicated` and `sum` in case *a* and *b* are `unique`:

```
sum(duplicated(c(a,b)))
#[1] 3
```

otherwise use in addition `unique`:

```
sum(duplicated(c(unique(a),unique(b))))
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%in%` :

```
a = 10:15
b = 13:17

length_equal <- function(x, y) sum(unique(x) %in% unique(y))
length_equal(a, b)
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
a <- 10:15
b <- 13:17

my_func <- function(a, b) length(a) - length(setdiff(a, b))
my_func(a, b)
#[1] 3
```